# What's a good way to store ActiveRecord queries (not the results of the query)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have certain conditions in my application that I need to query for regularly (like all users that have signed up in the last 24 hours), and I want to store that query for later use. What's a good way to store the query itself, not the results of the query?

A few different ways I've thought of:

1. Hash that maps keys to symbols that I use as functions, each function is defined on the `User` object, and its implementation defines the query I want.
2. Hash that maps keys to raw SQL queries.
3. Global hash of singleton methods that stores each query.

Comment: What's the motivation to write stored sql queries rather than have a model method that executes the desired active record relation query and call that method on demand?

Comment: Agreed. Or this is reporting, and doesn't even need to be in the app, but a reporting engine. But I don't see why you don't just have normal AR queries.

Comment: That's actually sort of what I'm getting at in the first suggestion above. A bunch of model methods that I have a hash of key => method_name for. Like if I want to have a select tag that lets you choose which query to run, the key could be the human readable name, and then I'd take that value and look it up in the hash, then run that function.